# How was this approximation made? (Archimedes law and weights)

Tags: buoyancy, fluid-statics, approximations

Excerpt from textbook:

> According to Archimedes' law the weight of a body of mass $m$ and density $\rho$ inside air is:
>   $$G=mg\left(1 - \frac{\rho_v}{\rho}\right)$$
>   Where $\rho_v$ is the density of air.
>   A "weight" of mass $m_t$ and density $\rho_t$ in air weights
>   $$G_t = m_tg\left(1-\frac{\rho_v}{\rho_t}\right)$$
>   If using a balance scale one determined $G=G_t$ one would get:
>   $$m=m_t\frac{(1 - \rho_v/\rho_t)}{(1-\rho_v/\rho)}$$
>   i.e. The mass of the weight and the mass of the body are **not equal**. In real measurments $\rho_v/\rho_t\ll1$ and $\rho_v/\rho\ll1$ so the previous equation can be approximately written as:
>   $$m=m_t\left(1+\frac{\rho_v}{\rho} - \frac{\rho_v}{\rho_t}\right)$$

How was the last approximation made? I tried deriving the 4th equation starting from the 3rd equation:

$$m- m_t  - m\frac{\rho_v}{\rho}  + m_t\frac{\rho_v}{\rho_t} = 0$$
Using *approximation magic* (perhaps the fact $\rho_v/\rho_t\ll1$ and $\rho_v/\rho\ll1$) I *may* turn $m$ into $m_t$ in the 3rd addend and factor $m_t$ :
$$m- m_t  - m_t\frac{\rho_v}{\rho}  + m_t\frac{\rho_v}{\rho_t} = 0$$
$$m- m_t\left(1 + \frac{\rho_v}{\rho} - \frac{\rho_v}{\rho_t}\right) = 0$$
That gives me the formula I wanted.
But it doesn't make any sense and probably another line of logic was used.

Comment: Guess you've not heard of the [binomial approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_approximation)? Direct application of it leads to your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For x<<1 the following common approximation is true:

1/(1-x)=1+x

So for y<<1 we get:

(1-y)/(1-x)=(1-y)(1+x)=1-y+x

The -xy component in the last equation is negligible, as it contains a product of two small values.